# How to query dates using sqlite between

Tags: sqlite, android-sqlite

Im trying to query a range between dates but

i have tried using the date datatype,store the values in the date column as string and also use the date function but not getting the desired results

```
CREATE TABLE PvcTable (
    date        TEXT NOT NULL,
    Wardname    TEXT NOT NULL,
    Puname      TEXT NOT NULL,
    PvcReceived TEXT,
    PRIMARY KEY (
        date,
        Wardname,
        Puname
    )
);
```

the expected result is when i query let say

```
SELECT *  from pvctable 
where date between '2019-1-1' and '2019-12-1' 
order by WARDNAME
```

i should get all the records between jan - dec 2019, but instead i get
this.only 3 records return.

```
date     Wardname       Puname                    PvcReceived
2019-10  01Alagarno     010KANGARWAPRISCHII         58
2019-11  02Baga         001MILEFOUR                 58
2019-12  02Baga         002DARBASHATA               58
```

Comment: new to the forum sorry about the post please...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is important to make sure that the dates in the table have the proper format `YYYY-MM-DD` which is comparable.
From the sample data you posted I see that there is no `DD` part in the dates, which is fine if you don't need it, because `YYYY-MM` is also comparable.
But if there is no `DD` part then in your query you should not compare the date column with dates containing this part, but with dates in the format `YYYY-MM`.
So change to this:

```
SELECT *  from pvctable 
where date between '2019-01' and '2019-12' 
order by WARDNAME
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gLerrZRuASGPqVDCKoPMje/0).
Results:

```
| date    | Wardname   | Puname              | PvcReceived |
| ------- | ---------- | ------------------- | ----------- |
| 2019-01 | 01Alagarno | 001ALAGARNOPRISCH   | 58          |
| 2019-10 | 01Alagarno | 010KANGARWAPRISCHII | 58          |
| 2019-11 | 02Baga     | 001MILEFOUR         | 58          |
| 2019-12 | 02Baga     | 002DARBASHATA       | 58          |
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but i have tried same but the result is the problem still persist. and yes my date format is yyyy-mm as your appropriately mentioned. pls assist

Comment: Post sample data. If the format of the dates is as in your question then you should get correct results.

Comment: Make sure the month part of your dates are 2 digits and not 1: `2019-05` and not `2019-5`

Comment: good observation , i will make the month part 2digits instead of 1. will get feed u back in a moment. thanks alot